# Magento 2 How to remove default website checkbox checked while add new product?

Tags: product, product-attribute, catalog, adminform, magento-2.2.5

Magento 2.2.5. I have set up a multi website and it is working fine.

My problem is when admin create any new product **Product in website** field default website selection checkbox is checked by default. so reason for this product is automatically assign to default website.

But i want to remove the default website checkbox checked and give required validation to this fields so admin have a attention to select website scope while create new product.

For more information check below screen-shoot.

**Default add new product form**

[image]

**What i want after modification**

[image]

---

**Edit :**

Answer of **@Idham Choudry** is right for single website because there is only single checkbox for select product in website, but when i use this for multi-website there is more than two checkbox so all the checkbox are required. so ideally & in my case if we select any one checkbox then there is not necessary to select all checkbox. In short all checkbox is not required, if we select any one then validation will be remove.

---

**Try with JavaScript way**

1. Include custom JS using XML in below file

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml

```
<head>
    <link src="Namespace_modulename::js/website_validation.js"/>
</head>
```

2. My custom JS in below path

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/website_validation.js

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
  $('#save-button').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var test = $(".admin__fieldset-product-websites :input").is(":checked");
            console.log(test);
});
```

Using this way my custom JS is load successfully but i can't give a validation to **Product in website** checkbox field.

Can anyone help me to solved out this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This checkbox fields is generated by virtualtype inside `app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<item name="websites" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Websites</item>
     <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
</item>
```

You need to override this inside your module `Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` like this:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="websites" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Websites</item>
                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Now you need to create new ui dataprovider file that will be extending the core file, and modify the `getFieldsForFieldset()` fuction which generate Product in Websites checkboxes, the new file will be located in `Namespace/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Websites.php` :

```
namespace Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;

class Websites extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Websites{
   protected function getFieldsForFieldset()
    {
        $children = [];
        $websiteIds = $this->getWebsitesValues();
        $websitesList = $this->getWebsitesList();
        $isNewProduct = !$this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        $tooltip = [
            'link' => 'http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html',
            'description' => __(
                'If your Magento installation has multiple websites, ' .
                'you can edit the scope to use the product on specific sites.'
            ),
        ];
        $sortOrder = 0;
        $label = __('Websites');

        $defaultWebsiteId = $this->websiteRepository->getDefault()->getId();
        foreach ($websitesList as $website) {
            $isChecked = in_array($website['id'], $websiteIds)
                || ($defaultWebsiteId == $website['id'] && $isNewProduct);
            $children[$website['id']] = [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Form\Element\Checkbox::NAME,
                            'description' => __($website['name']),
                            'tooltip' => $tooltip,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'dataScope' => 'website_ids.' . $website['id'],
                            'label' => $label,
                            'valueMap' => [
                                'true' => (string)$website['id'],
                                'false' => '0',
                            ],
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => true,
                                'validate-number' => true,
                            ],
                            'value' => $isChecked ? (string)$website['id'] : ''
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ];

            $sortOrder++;
            $tooltip = null;
            $label = ' ';

            if (!$isNewProduct && !in_array($website['id'], $websiteIds) && $website['storesCount']) {
                $children['copy_to_stores.' . $website['id']] = $this->getDynamicRow($website['id'], $sortOrder);
                $sortOrder++;
            }
        }

        return $children;
    }
}
```

in the above code i just add the `required-entry` as validation and remove the default value for checkbox `''value' => $isChecked ? (string)$website['id'] : ''`, and the result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for giving your valuable time. i was try your above code it is give required  but product form is save without checkbox is checked when it is required field.

Comment: @ChiragPatel check for my updated answer, i just add more validation

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: Validation is working but both checkbox are required field in multiwebsite in my case, it is not necessary to select both checkbox.